# Changing lead owner to existing Account Owner

Tags: apex, trigger, process-builder

I have formula field called "domain__c" on Lead object which comes from the email field.
I also have a domain field on Account object.

I want to change the lead owner to the person who owns the existing Account if it does exist by matching the Domain__c fields. Is this achievable using process builder?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Process Builder by itself won't get you all the way there. There's simply no way to perform a query using the Process Builder (unless I'm missing something). However, you could build a flow that queries the account's owner and updates the lead owner field as a result, and then have the Process Builder kick off that flow. Note that if the account field is a formula, you may end up with non-selective query errors because of full table scans. In that case, you'll need to make a domain field that's text so it can be properly indexed and filtered against.

Comment: The domain field on Account is a string field but the domain field on Lead is a formula field. 
So an After insert trigger would be a better solution?